# Redirect old page url after .htaccess url rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, rule

I have rewrited my url's with htaccess and now I want to redirect the old url's to the new ones, but I can't figure it out how to do it after all.

This is my redirect rule used:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)/$ /page.php?name=$1 [L]
```

The old url's look like this: page.php?name=page-name

The new url's look like this: /page/page-name/

Comment: So what's wrong? What problems are you experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit complex when you want redirect an url with GET parameters.

Here's a trick to do it :

```
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ %{QUERY_STRING} [C]
RewriteRule name=(.*) /page/$1/? [R=301,L]
```

Explainations :

- First, you redirect `page.php?name=page-name` to `?name=page-name`
- Then, you ask using the following rule for this result (with `[C]` tag)
- Third, you redirect `page-name`, picked with `(.*)` to `page/page-name/`
- Last trick, if you don't put the last `?`, your query string will be appended to your result and you'll have this kind of url : `page/page-name/?name=page-name`. Using an useless `?` erase the old GET parameters.

Found some informations here :

- [Apache mod_rewrite doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)
- [How to strip a query string](http://dranger.com/weblog/entry/apache_mod_rewrite_strip_query_string.html)

Comment: I tried to use your code and the redirect works, but I get an error when using together with the rewrite rule:

"The page isn't redirecting properly
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."

Comment: Try by replacing the rule by `^name=(.*)$` (please note it works fine on a basic testing archi)