# URL Rewrite querystring in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

I've spent a couple of hours trying to achieve something I thought was easy.
I have `domain.tld/index.php?site=Page` and want to turn it `domain.tld/Page`. The `?site=Page` is relative to what it gets from the MySQL database.

At some point I had it make an endless loop, but everything else didn't effect anything.
It might have something to do with, that I don't understand the ^ in RewriteRule and Cond.
But the structure is `/var/www/whine/skovtrup` -- `whine` is the domain and `skovtrup` is a folder where I work with the website I need rewrite on.
`<Directory>` is set to `/var/www/whine` in the sites-enabled file.

I really hope you guys can help me.

Just to sum up:

- Replace ?site=Page with /Page/
- Page is relative.
- Placed in /var/www/whine/skovtrup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this code helps you ?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /skovtrup/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ %{QUERY_STRING} [C]
RewriteRule site=(.*) /skovtrup/$1? [R=301,L]
```

`^` char represents the url start, and `$` the end.

For my code, see some explainations here : [Redirect old page url after .htaccess url rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011526/redirect-old-page-url-after-htaccess-url-rewriting)

Comment: I've moved it to another unused domain, for the testing. But it doesn't work. I get error 500 when trying. (Removed the folder and tried to change to code to match)
It didn't work before I moved it, and the changes I've made doesn't work either.

Comment: It works for me with a basic archi (`localhost/skovtrup/`). You should have some parasite code. Have you tried write the absolute path for the 301 redirection ? (actually `/skovtrup/$1?`)

Comment: Just to be sure. Where do you put the .htaccess file?

Comment: In `/var/www/whine/skovtrup/`